# Global variable optimisation in anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, visual-c++, clang

Here is an example:

```cpp
namespace {
    int a = 0;
}

int main() {
    a = 1;
}
```

[GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/shh9zE) and [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/Eqa4Wq) optimized `a = 1` out, but [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/Y955j3) didn't.

Example of output from GCC:

```
main:
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Another example:

```cpp
namespace {
    int a = 0;
}

int main() {
    a++;
}
```

None of compilers optimized out `a++`: [GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/Tv3GPq), [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/GThxxr), [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/eGW5zj).

Example of output from GCC:

```
main:
        add     DWORD PTR _ZN12_GLOBAL__N_11aE[rip], 1
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
```

Is there some reasoning, why compilers do optimize some global variables, but do not optimize others? It is okay to make an answer for a specific compiler.

Comment: to optimize or not is not part of he tlanguage, so each compiler is free to do the optimizations it want while they are not incompatible with the language rules. Out of that rather than to ask why a compiler does not, so people working on it do not, why are you not asking yourself why you did that kind of code ? why to protest and ask others to optimize your poor code rather than to not code like that ? (please don't get that remark bad, is just to make my sentence more explicit). Also what about to participate to compiler implementations ?

Comment: Why don't you run the programs through a profiler, to see if *anything* there actually makes any difference.

Comment: @bruno I often get this remark. But this remark never explains why it is like that. Also compilers are often not so free to not optimize. There is such thing as missing optimization, which you can report to compiler team. So I am asking about the reasoning of the optimizations.

Comment: @adrian-mole Reading an assembly is not enough? It is obvious that `a++` consumes time.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP a compiler is a program like any others,  they do things and they don't do others. The list of potential optimizations is infinite, while the time to develop them nor the number of people working on them are  infinite then by definition all potential optimizations are not done. Anyway the list of optimizations  already done is incredible, and be sure you do not know that list so long it is ... nor me

Comment: @bruno If I don't know something - I can ask question on the stackoverflow 

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP for sure, and I try to explain from my (limited) knowledge and experiences ;-) Did you already implemented compiler(s) ? If no can I propose you to implement a compiler even for a very more simple language than C++ to understand more the problems ?

Comment: `Did you already implemented compiler(s) ? If no can I propose you to implement a compiler even for a very more simple language than C++ to understand more the problems` I do love to play with LLVM. I always see that LLVM doesn't like to optimize out private global variables, even if it is obvious that they should be optimized out.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Generally, it might not be that obvious. "Private" global variables may be used outside of `main` and it may not be that easy for a compiler to prove the opposite.

Comment: @daniel-langr It is great to hear this. Can you tell an example, how variable can be used, if there is only one private global and only one function as in the example? It is really interesting.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Recall the word _"generally"_ in my previous comment.

Comment: @daniel-langr okay :'( I was just interested if you know some cases where it actually happens.

Comment: @CPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPPCPP Look, e.g., [here](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2019/04/08/a-general-overview-of-what-happens-before-main/#returning) (section _Returning From `main`_) or [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/functions-that-are-executed-before-and-after-main-in-c/).

Comment: @daniel-langr I don't think if libc stuff is somehow important in this case. It shouldn't touch this global variable. Also it is okay to give any other strange name to variable and function. Result is the same.

Comment: Seems to me like just a missed optimization.  There are many other combinations that do get optimized out.  Note it can also be reproduced with `static int a;` either at file scope or inside `main`.

Comment: I will note that `a = 1` performs a write, but not a read, so the compilers are probably realizing this. On the other hand, `a++` performs a read and a write, and the compilers don't seem to notice that the only reads never escape (they're only ever used to write the variable).

Comment: @justin Looks like a good point. Examples of addition https://godbolt.org/z/KhPYqo and assign https://godbolt.org/z/e4ve7f in clang say that maybe it is a reason...

Comment: @justin Fun part is, that loading alone by itself does not make any harm too https://godbolt.org

Comment: Edit: https://godbolt.org/z/fo4srP for last comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first example, MSVC will also optimize out the global (and writing to it) if you use the `/GL` flag. Unfortunately, when you do so, it doesn't produce assembly language output, so Godbolt will just tell you the output file is missing. To examine the code, you have to generate an actual executable, then disassemble it, to get:

```
0000000140001000: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
0000000140001002: C3                 ret
```

...but even `/GL` won't optimize out the increment for your second case:

```
0000000140001000: FF 05 AA 6B 01 00  inc         dword ptr [0000000140017BB0h]
0000000140001006: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
0000000140001008: C3                 ret
```

The "why" is hard to answer, simply because it comes down to the motivations of the people working on compiler optimizations. I'd guess, however, that they mostly respond to (at least perceived) needs of their customers. So, for gcc a lot comes down to things like whether a particular optimization will significantly help (or hurt) the performance of popular open source packages such as Linux. Likewise, for MSVC it's largely about popular packages like Windows and Office (and no I don't mean to imply that they ignore their outside customers either).

So in this case, you have code that has a minuscule effect once when the program starts. The big question then is whether that translates into bigger effects on other code that's common enough that they'd have some motivation to optimize it out. I'd guess that at least so far, they simply haven't see many cases where that arises. Given how often most people create and initialize a global variable, and ignore it from then on, my guess is they simply haven't see much reason to work on this particular case. It's optimized only to the extent that it's similar enough to be affected by optimizations they write primarily for other situations. For example, if you add another modification of `a`, on this general order:

```cpp
namespace {
int a = 0;
}

void foo()
{
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
        a++;
}

int main()
{
    a++;
    foo();
}
```

...it's probably no surprise that the compiler will turn the separate increment operations into a single assignment:

```
0000000140001000: C7 05 A6 6B 01 00  mov         dword ptr [0000000140017BB0h],0Bh
                  0B 00 00 00
000000014000100A: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
000000014000100C: C3                 ret
```

But this is just applying basic strength reduction, one of the standard optimizations that's been well known for decades, and most compilers have done just almost that long. I suppose you could make an argument that eliminating the global is just an application of dead code elimination, but being a global variable makes it kind of a special case, so even though they clearly do dead code elimination in general, it doesn't get applied (consistently) in this case.